# How would I do a side NavBar that also has words sideways

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I Seen examples where the words are horizontal but not when words are vertical. Is there a way to achieve this in Flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RotatedBox`

```
new RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1,
  child: new Text("Lorem ipsum")
)
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Guess there really is a widget for everything.